# Mock patch a function that doesn't exist on a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

Using Python's [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) framework, is it possible to mock patch a function that doesn't exist on a class. If so, how?

For example:

*example.py*

```
import mock
import unittest


class MyClass(object):
    pass


class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mock_non_existent_function(self):
        with mock.patch('example.MyClass.my_function'):
            pass
```

Running that test raises an error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jesse/Code/my_proj/lib/mock.py", line 1193, in patched
  File "/Users/jesse/Code/my_proj/lib/mock.py", line 1268, in __enter__
  File "/Users/jesse/Code/my_proj/lib/mock.py", line 1242, in get_original
AttributeError: <class 'example.MyClass'> does not have the attribute 'my_function'
```

Using `Python 2.7.9` and `mock 1.0.1`.

Comment: Instead of using `patch` you could just do `example.MyClass.my_function = Mock()`. That does mean you don't have the cleanup though.

Comment: @ThomWiggers How would I go about cleaning up after doing a monkey patch like that?

Comment: Euh, I guess `del example.MyClass.my_function` should work...

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer here is to use the `create` parameter:

```
with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_function', create=True)
```

This works when replacing the equivalent line in the original code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the function you want to patch in somehow. 
From the [mock docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch):

```
>>> class Class(object):
...     def method(self):
...         pass
...
>>> with patch('__main__.Class') as MockClass:
...     instance = MockClass.return_value
...     instance.method.return_value = 'foo'
...     assert Class() is instance
...     assert Class().method() == 'foo'
...
```

Comment: I can't mock out the entire class because I want all the real code to execute other than the function I am trying to mock. Furthermore, this only works if `method()` is defined on the class. My question specifically asks how to mock a function which is not defined on the class. Running your code without the `def method...` part gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'method'`.